# How can Durandal bundle views?

Tags: durandal

When deploying an enterprise Durandal application with hundreds of views, is there a way to bundle the html templates so that little http requests for every view can be avoided in favor of a single, compiled html view?

Answer (score 0):

With Durandal, you're developing a *single-page* application, so there's only one, up-front request made for views.  Caching and other optimizations, including optimization with Weyland, Durandal's build system, can tweak that further.

There are circumstances where you may wish to load views in a different way, and those can be achieved with Durandal as well.

Comment: Is there any documentation on how the view bundling works / can be configured?  Is this the case OOB?

Comment: For build documentation, see http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Weyland.html.  This covers Weyland, but other build systems are given in the documentation as well.  For basic information on how SPAs work, you should watch John Papa's Pluralsight course _Single Page Apps with HTML5, Web API, Knockout and jQuery_.

Answer (score 0):

After you built your app with, for example, Grunt (http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Grunt.html) you are getting one big file 'main-built.js' with all your javascripts buldled together. The thing that I didn't realise at first, was that all the .html views are also bundled into this file. I was expecting to see them bundled into 'index.html' or something like that (compiled html view). But actually views are compiled into Javascript.